# How do I make the frame keep repainting until window close?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently making a cube (drawing with point2d and line2d to make the shape) move around a frame, similar to that of pong or the window screen saver bubbles. i am able to print the cube onto the frame but i don't understand how to make it move around after the first print. I want to use a timer action listener to make the ball move around.

Viewer

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CubeBounceViewer {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("Cube Bounce");
        frame.setSize(1280,720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CubeBounceComponent component = new CubeBounceComponent();
        frame.add(component);
    }
}
```

Component

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CubeBounceComponent extends JComponent{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Creates a object list with size equal to value of instance
        Cube cube = new Cube();

        class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                cube.move();
            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();

        final int DELAY = 100;
        Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
        t.start();

        cube.draw(g2);
        cube.move();
        if (cube.getX()>=1265 || cube.getX()<=15 && cube.getY()<=15 || cube.getY()>=705) {
            cube.changeDirection(-1, -1);
        } else if(cube.getX()>=1265 || cube.getX()<=15) {
            cube.changeDirection(-1, 1);
        } if (cube.getY()<=15 || cube.getY()>=705) {
            cube.changeDirection(1,-1);
        }

    }
}
```

Cube

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Cube {
    private int centerX,centerY,directionX, directionY;

    public Cube() {
        centerX=640;
        centerY=360;
        directionX=1;
        directionY=1;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        Point2D.Double backTopLeft = new Point2D.Double(centerX-10,centerY-15);
        Point2D.Double backTopRight = new Point2D.Double(centerX+15,centerY-15);
        Point2D.Double backBottomLeft = new Point2D.Double(centerX-10,centerY+10);
        Point2D.Double backBottomRight = new Point2D.Double(centerX+15,centerY+10);
        Point2D.Double frontTopLeft = new Point2D.Double(centerX-15,centerY-10);
        Point2D.Double frontTopRight = new Point2D.Double(centerX+10,centerY-10);
        Point2D.Double frontBottomLeft = new Point2D.Double(centerX-15,centerY+15);
        Point2D.Double frontBottomRight = new Point2D.Double(centerX+10,centerY+15);

        Line2D.Double backTop = new Line2D.Double(backTopLeft,backTopRight);
        Line2D.Double backRight = new Line2D.Double(backTopRight,backBottomRight);
        Line2D.Double backLeft = new Line2D.Double(backTopLeft,backBottomLeft);
        Line2D.Double backBottom = new Line2D.Double(backBottomLeft,backBottomRight);
        Line2D.Double frontTop = new Line2D.Double(frontTopLeft,frontTopRight);
        Line2D.Double frontRight = new Line2D.Double(frontTopRight,frontBottomRight);
        Line2D.Double frontLeft = new Line2D.Double(frontTopLeft,frontBottomLeft);
        Line2D.Double frontBottom = new Line2D.Double(frontBottomLeft,frontBottomRight);
        Line2D.Double topLeft = new Line2D.Double(backTopLeft,frontTopLeft);
        Line2D.Double topRight = new Line2D.Double(backTopRight,frontTopRight);
        Line2D.Double bottomLeft = new Line2D.Double(backBottomLeft,frontBottomLeft);
        Line2D.Double bottomRight = new Line2D.Double(backBottomRight,frontBottomRight);

         g2.draw(backTop);
         g2.draw(backRight);
         g2.draw(backLeft);
         g2.draw(backBottom);
         g2.draw(frontTop);
         g2.draw(frontRight);
         g2.draw(frontLeft);
         g2.draw(frontBottom);
         g2.draw(topLeft); 
         g2.draw(topRight);
         g2.draw(bottomLeft);
         g2.draw(bottomRight); 
    }

    public void changeDirection(int x, int y) {
        directionX*=x;
        directionY*=y;
    }
    public void move() {
        centerX+=1*directionX;
        centerY+=1*directionY;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return centerX;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return centerY;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You're doing a bunch of stuff in your paint component that you should not be doing. That should *only* repaint the component. The whole cube.move and bounds checking should be done in a completely different method.

Comment: I have some idea of what I can do to make bounds checking a different method. I don't understand how to make the whole cube move a separate. How will the computer automatically repaint itself?

Comment: Repaints happen often, you can request a repaint or if something changes in the scene the paintComponent can be called. Right now you are always creating a new cube in your paint component. You never paint the updated cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make the cube a member of your class, not a local variable. Second remove all of the moving logic from your paint component. Third Request a repaint after you've updated the cubes position.

```
Cube cube = new Cube();

public void updatePosition(){


    cube.move();
    if (cube.getX()>=1265 || cube.getX()<=15 && cube.getY()<=15 || cube.getY()>=705) {
        cube.changeDirection(-1, -1);
    } else if(cube.getX()>=1265 || cube.getX()<=15) {
        cube.changeDirection(-1, 1);
    } if (cube.getY()<=15 || cube.getY()>=705) {
        cube.changeDirection(1,-1);
    }
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    cube.draw(g2);
}
```

Now, you have a cube that can change position. You also have a method to change the position. So in your main method create a timer that calls the update method.

```
    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            component.updatePosition();
        }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();

    final int DELAY = 100;
    Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
    t.start();
```

Note you can use lambdas to make this a little more concise, and not need the named class `TimerListener`.

```
Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, evt->component.updatePosition() )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work. Now my only problem is that over time, the amount of times cube.move() is called seems to happen sooner and sooner or something. Do you know what's causing it?

Comment: @Nonstopbrain Probably because you're creating more and more timers. Just start one timer that calls the update posotions. Ill update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. Seeing how you explained my problems and seeing the steps made made it easier for me to understand why things went where. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried putting your code in a:

```
While (true) {}
```

Comment: when i implemented it before the cube.draw(g2)  and i compile it, the cube doesn't show up and i won't be able to close window unless i stop the console or something. I'm using Eclipse IDE to program this.